Oracle Apex: Datepicker returning week number
I am trying to get a date picker to return the week number of the selected date in a different page item.
I've read a lot of other posts saying to use: select to char( to_date (DATECOL, 'DD/MM/YYY'), 'IW' from TABLE.
I have been putting variations of this code into the DEFAULT SQL Query section of the page item I want to display as week number. But I cannot for the life of me get this to work?
I am very new to the whole Apex system and any help would be greatly appreciated.

So, what values are in your DATECOL? What is the data type? What do you get from just to_date()?

DATECOL is the date from the datepicker. I don't entirely know what to_date does, I have been trying to understand from other posts like this: https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/date-picker-returning-week-number-8371 that is why I am asking for help...

Since we don't know your data some dummy ones are used - here is test table (sample data) having date as date datatype (DATE_COL) and as varchar datatype (VARCHAR_DATE_COL) along with ISO week number as number datatype (WEEK_NUM).



ID
DATE_COL
VARCHAR_DATE_COL
WEEK_NUM




1
20-DEC-24
20.12.2024
51


1
27-DEC-24
27.12.2024
52


1
28-DEC-24
28.12.2024
52


1
29-DEC-24
29.12.2024
52




Create page item as Date Picker - name it as you wish (P99_PICKED_DATE) and define format that you want (dd.mm.yyyy) your Date Picker Item to hold. The same format will be used in Where clause if you use it to filter table data (2.1). If you just want to extract week number from date picked then the format will be used in select statement (2.2)

2.1 SQL selecting from sample data using Where clause to fetch matching week number
Select tt.*, To_Char(DATE_COL, 'iw') "WEEK_FROM_DATE_COL", To_Char(DATE_COL, 'iw') "WEEK_FROM_VARCHAR_DATE_COL"
From    TEST_TABLE tt
Where tt.WEEK_NUM = To_Number(To_Char(To_Date(:P99_PICKED_DATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'iw'))

R e s u l t :



ID
DATE_COL
VARCHAR_DATE_COL
WEEK_NUM
WEEK_FROM_DATE_COL
WEEK_FROM_VARCHAR_DATE_COL




1
27-DEC-24
27.12.2024
52
52
52


1
28-DEC-24
28.12.2024
52
52
52


1
29-DEC-24
29.12.2024
52
52
52



2.2  Extracting ISO week number from date picked
Select To_Number(To_Char(To_Date(:P99_PICKED_DATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'iw')) "WEEK_NUM" From Dual

NOTE:
Date picker value is text but it should have a valid date representation defined by format - using the same format you can convert it to date where needed.
If your week number column is of Varchar2 datatype you should ommit converting it to  number.
